# Jquery CSS transform not working in IE8?

Tags: jquery, css

When comes to using CSS3 that doesn't support older browser like IE8, I would apply them using jquery instead, but I noticed the CSS transform in Jquery doesn't work....

My code:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/hydxE

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: jQuery simply sets inline styles. It doesn't make IE8 magically support extra features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 transforms don't work in IE8. jQuery will add vendor prefixes to CSS for you (As of version 1.8.0 at least), but that's it. You'll have to find some non CSS way to achieve this effect if IE8 support is essential.